# Japanese Names in PayPal's response _notify-synch

Tags: php, paypal

I am not able to extract and save the correct names of Japanese customers. After reading the response from PayPal using `fgets` from a `fsockopen` handler when written to error log it looks like below:

```
charset=windows-1252
first_name=%1A%1A
last_name=%1A%1A
```

I had to change PayPal settings to receive responses in utf-8. Now the values appear like below:

```
first_name=%E4%BD%B3%E5%B9%B8
last_name=%E4%BD%90%E8%97%A4
```

What's the right way to read from such a stream correctly? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I had to change language settings at PayPal to utf-8
2. Then do urlencode on each returned value to get japanese characters.